# Software license for non-commerical reproducible research

Tags: copyright, software, licensing

I am a researcher at a university with a guest status. I am not employed though and the work I do is my own. The software I develop belongs to me. For [reproducible research](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reproducibility#Reproducible_research) I want to publish some of my software on github and I am searching for an appropriate license. Reproducible research means that other researcher can look at my code and try it out (on my data, which I also need to provide) to see if the claims of my publication are true.

I do not want it to be open source (in the strict sense), because I do not want to allow companies to use it for profit. I only want to publish it to enable reproducible research, but I want to keep as much of the rights for myself.

I want to keep the right to have (copies) of my work licensed under different licenses so that I am able to use it myself any way I want in the future (e.g. commercially) or give copies with more permissive licenses to other people. I interpret https://law.stackexchange.com/a/36565/36090 such that I - as the copyright holder - can do that no matter which license my "first" license is, but I am not sure.

I do not want to actively encourage contribution to the software (it is not supposed to be a widely usable library), but I am not against it either. If there is no license that allows contribution I don't mind.

As a law-novice it seemed to me that the CC BY-NC-SA or the CC BY-NC-ND license might be right for me, but the [creative commons licenses state](https://creativecommons.org/faq/#can-i-apply-a-creative-commons-license-to-software) that they should not be used for software.

I guess, I am searching for (1) an alternative to CC BY-NC-SA and (2) an alternative to CC BY-NC-ND for software. But - again - as a law novice I am not sure if that is actually right.

Comment: Ask your university's legal department for help.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch: Thanks for the idea - didn't occur to me!

Comment: Unfortunately, this is off-topic for Open Source as it is asking for recommendations for a non-open source license (within the scope of this site).

Comment: @PhilipKendall: I know. I did not do the migration...